# NoMethodError undefined method any? for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a report which collects product data based on sales. I'm getting an error message in my haml that I can't seem to track down.

Error: `NoMethodError undefined method`any?' for nil:NilClass`

Controller:

```
class Admin::SalesController < Admin::Controller
  def index
    results = Search.admin_search_orders(params)
    @results = SalesAdminViewModel.new(results, params)
  end

  def show
    product = Product.find_by_number(params[:id])
    @product = SalesViewModel.new(product)
  end
end
```

ViewModel:

```
  def products
    return @products if defined?(@products)

    models = Catalog::Product.find_ordered(map(&:catalog_id))
    view_models = SalesAdminViewModel.wrap(models)

    @products = PagedArray.from(view_models, page, per_page, total)
  end

  def sorts
    @sorts ||= Search.product_sorts.map do |sort|
      [sort.name, sort.slug]
    end
  end
```

Html.haml:

```
%h1 Product Sales

  - if @products.any?

    .mp-browse.mp-cf
      - if @products.num_pages > 1
        = render 'admin/shared/pagination', collection: @products
```

Comment: `@products` is empty, you are not instantiating it in the controller.

Comment: After updating my controller to be the below show method, I'm still encountering the same error.
    `products = Product.find_by_number(params[:id])`
    `@products = SalesViewModel.new(products)`

Comment: Well, it is `nil` still then, try `= @products.inspect` in your view, then you can see what `@products` contains.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I see where it's showing up as nil now. So this means my collection of products aren't being gathered and therefore can't render on the page. Then, would be something I could resolve within the model by building my collection?

Comment: `SalesViewModel.new(products)` is returning`nil` for some reason. I find it easiest to play around in the console when debugging something like this `rails c`

Comment: If you show your whole `SalesViewModel` that would help too

Comment: Are you returning anything from the `initialize` method in the view model?

Comment: I'm object composition to grab the functionality from a different class. So basically, there's no initialize method and viewmodel actually looks like what's posted above.

Comment: Yes, but at some point you must return the value to the `@products` variable in the controller.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for doing `@product.products.any?` in the view?